# In Visual Studio 2012/2013 is there any way to filter out CodeReview shelvesets?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, shelveset, tfs-code-review

We've started doing code reviews in VisualStudio which is great however it creates a shelveset for each code review.

Now when I open the Find Shelvesets window, the list is polluted with all the code review shelvesets.

Is there any way to filter these out the CodeReview shelvesets from the list?

Comment: It seems indeed strange that the shelvesets "CodeReview_" are linked to the code review, so if you delete these, the link is also broken ???

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at [Review Assistant](http://www.devart.com/review-assistant/) which provides similar but more elaborated functionality as compared to built-in code review feature.

It allows you to review code without creating numerous shelvesets. So you won't experience the problem described above.

Comment: Pre-commit reviews still require the (manual) creation of shelvesets, is that correct?

Comment: @BrettPostin No. Just request a review and it will automatically create a shelfset.